# Remove newline from openssl base64 encode string?

Tags: command-line, openssl

```
echo -n 'HelloWorld' | openssl base64 | pbcopy
```

That command give me a newline after paste it.

I thought the -n removed the newline but don't remove when use base64.

so how can get my output string without a newline?

Comment: If the output is base64 encoded, what difference does a newline make? Anyway, you can just delete newlines using `tr`: `echo -n ... base64 | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy`. Are you using OSX?

Comment: 1) I want avoid the newline because affect the output, I mean I need the output clean, I use base64 to create passwords, so when paste with newline of course give an alert of wrong password. 2) yes Im on OSX 3) now works with echo -n 'HelloWorld' | openssl base64 | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. No sane base64 decoder will care about newlines.

Comment: works like this: `echo -n 'helloworld' | openssl base64 | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy`

Comment: Questions on OSX should be posted on [apple.se] or [unix.se]. (yes, that's how it works).

Comment: ouch! sorry, Im new and can't find the mac channel, thank you; is possible move this or delete? well I got my answer thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP uses software not found in Ubuntu but rather in Mac OS X

Comment: @muru in a telnet session (while debugging) the new line will trigger data sending

Comment: this is actually pretty simple if you use printf:

Comment: echo "some long string" | base64 | while read line; do printf $line; done

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there's simpler ways to do it, but here I'm using awk with output record separator blank. Being there only one record separator, the result will be blank. Now, I can test if there is newline or not by running output to file and `cat -A` that file to show metacharacters.

```
$ printf 'Hello World' | openssl base64 | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="";} {print}' > tester.txt

$ cat -A tester.txt
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=
```

As you can see, there is no $ sign at the end of that string, hence no new line.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**